# Is it possible way for allow RTSP protocol in broadcasting?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rtsp, broadcast, agora.io

I am using React SDK for Broadcasting with RTSP Link. But It's not supporting. We got below error.

> chunk-K5SOP2KC.js?v=4001314d:8961 Uncaught (in promise) AgoraRTCException: AgoraRTCError INVALID_OPERATION: [LiveStreaming] no transcoding config found, can not start transcoding streaming task

Here my code.

```
const agoraEngine = useRTCClient(AgoraRTC.createClient({ codec: "h264", mode: 'live' }));

 useJoin({
    appid: config.appId,
    channel: config.channelName,
    token: config.rtcToken,
    uid: config.uid,
  });

 usePublish([localCameraTrack,localMicrophoneTrack])

agoraEngine.setClientRole("host");
agoraEngine.setLiveTranscoding({width : 600 , height: 360,backgroundColor: 0x000000,  videoBitrate: 400,lowLatency: false})
agoraEngine.startLiveStreaming("rtsp://sampleurl/samplekey",true)
```